# tensorflow: ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution

This is the error i got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fully_connected_feed.py", line 387, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/home/-/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "fully_connected_feed.py", line 289, in main
    run_training()
  File "fully_connected_feed.py", line 256, in run_training
    saver.save(sess, checkpoint_file, global_step=step)
  File "/home/-/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1386, in save
    self.export_meta_graph(meta_graph_filename)
  File "/home/-/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1414, in export_meta_graph
    graph_def=ops.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(add_shapes=True),
  File "/home/-/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2257, in as_graph_def
    result, _ = self._as_graph_def(from_version, add_shapes)
  File "/home/-/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2220, in _as_graph_def
    raise ValueError("GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.")
ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.
```

I believe it is from the result of this code

```
weights = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="hidden1")[0]
weights = tf.scatter_nd_update(weights,indices, updates)
weights = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="hidden2")[0]
weights = tf.scatter_nd_update(weights,indices, updates)
```

I am not sure why my model is getting so big in size (15k steps and 240MB). Any thoughts? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what is happening without seeing the code, but in general TensorFlow model sizes will not increase with number of steps - they should be fixed.

If the model size is increasing with number of steps, it suggests that the computation graph is being added to on every step. For example, something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
  for i in xrange(1000):
    sess.run(tf.add(1, 2))
    # or perhaps sess.run(tf.scatter_nd_update(...)) in your case
```

will create 3000 nodes in the graph (one for add, one for '1' one for '2' on every iteration). Instead, you want to define your computational graph once and run repeatedly with something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.add(1, 2)
# or perhaps x = tf.scatter_nd_update(...) in your case
with tf.Session() as sess:
  for i in xrange(1000):
    sess.run(x)
```

Which will have a fixed graph of 3 nodes for all the 1000 (and any more) iterations. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I get your point on the model increasing, buti I nested `tf.scatter_nd_update(...)` because I needed to update my weights at each step (sort of a manual convolution). Perhaps it is the wrong way of doing so?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but doesn't the same apply? Don't call `tf.scatter_nd_update` inside the loop, but instead save the operation returned and call it in the loop. From the [documentation of `tf.scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd_update) - it applies the update and just returns the same value as the first argument for convenience. So you could do something like:

    update = tf.scatter_nd_update(weights, indices, updates)

    for i in xrange(num_steps):
        sess.run(update)